# Double border line for table

Tags: tables, layout

What I want to achieve is what is shown in the attached image at the bottom. The first problem is making a double line border. I have not gotten to try much, most I have done is google around and found different solutions to problems that seem similar but that I don't think can solve this problem.

What I did try is to put fbox-es inside fbox-es trying to get it to look like this. But I couldn't manage to put a fbox under another. I only managed to get them to stay besides each other and put several inside each fbox.

```
\begin{center}
    \fboxsep=3pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax
    \fbox{%
        \fboxsep=40pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{
            \fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{}
            \fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{}
        }
    
        \fboxsep=40pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{
            \fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{}
            \fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{}
        }
    }
\end{center}
```

Which resulted in this

[image]

I also tried this

```
\begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
        \hline
         & \fboxsep=10pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{hello} &  \\ \hline
         &  &  \\ \hline
         &  &  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Which resulted in this

[image]

As I said in the beginning of the question, what is shown in the image below is what I am trying to achieve, and the first thing I need help with is the double line border. I am not sure how easy it is to get the rest of the layout the way I want (with the image and text), so I would appreciate it if you could help me with that too. But first I need help with the double line border.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be interested in functionality provided by [`hhline`](//ctan.org/pkg/hhline):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx,hhline}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ || X || X || }
  \hhline{|t:==:t|}
  \multicolumn{2}{|| p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-4\arrayrulewidth-2\doublerulesep} ||}{%
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      \\
      \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image} \\
      \\
      Some text should go right here \\
      \\
      \Large Some larger text goes right here \\
      \mbox{}
    \end{tabular}
  } \\
  \hhline{|:=:t:=:|}
  & \\
  More text & More text here \\
  & \\
  Some text here as well & And then some more here \\
  & \\
  \hhline{|:=::=:|}
  & \\
  More text & \centering\arraybackslash
    \makebox[.8\linewidth]{\dotfill} \\
  & \\
  Some text here as well & And then some more here \\
  & \\
  \hhline{|b:=:b:=:b|}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The example in the [`hhline` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/hhline) provides a succinct display of the `\hhline` argument symbols and their resulting display:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have outer `\fbox`, two `\fbox`es at 2nd level and four `\fbox`es at 3rd level. You have at 2nd level: `\fbox`, space, `\par`, `\fbox`, space. The `\par` (from empty line) is ignored because we are in restricted horizontal mode. But the spaces (they come from end of lines) are not ignored. The first space is the space between two vertical rules in the center of your example picture and the second space makes the problem for you.

```
\begin{center}
    \fboxsep=3pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax
    \fbox{%
        \fboxsep=40pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{
            \fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{}
            \fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{}
        } %<- this space generates space between rules
    
        % ^^^ this empty line ^^^ is \par and it is ignored
        \fboxsep=40pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{
            \fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{}
            \fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{}
        } %<- this space is your problem.
    }
\end{center}
```

Solution:

```
 \begin{center}
    \fboxsep=3pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax
    \fbox{%
        \fboxsep=40pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{
            \fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{}
            \fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{}
        }\kern3pt %<- space with more controlled size
        %
        \fboxsep=40pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{
            \fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{}
            \fboxsep=5pt\relax\fboxrule=0.5pt\relax\fbox{}
        }% <- no space here
    }
\end{center}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping control the size using kern. I actually did not notice that that space was wrong. Though I don't understand how that last space is a problem for me. Also, this doesn't seem to help me put a fbox under the fbox-es inside the outer fbox, or am I missing something?

Comment: Try both examples above: with and without space. Do you see difference?

Comment: I am sorry, should have done that to begin with. I see now what happens with and without space, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 6.24 of 2023-09-28).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{XX}
  \Block{1-2}{
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      \\
      \includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image} \\
      \\
      Some text should go right here \\
      \\
      \Large Some larger text goes right here \\
      \mbox{}
    \end{tabular}
  } \\
  \Block{5-1}{} & \Block{5-1}{} \\
  More text & More text here \\
  \\
  Some text here as well & And then some more here \\
  \\
  \Block{5-1}{} & \Block{5-1}{} \\
  More text & \Block[transparent]{}{\makebox[.8\linewidth]{\dotfill}} \\
  \\
  Some text here as well & And then some more here \\
  & \\
\CodeAfter
  \TikzEveryCell{offset=1pt,draw}
  \tikz \draw ([xshift=-1pt,yshift=1pt]1-|1) 
              rectangle 
              ([xshift=1pt,yshift=-1pt]last-|last) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]